# Получение значения переменной jRuby скрипта в Java коде с использованием ScriptingContainer

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Решил к одному проекту прикрутить jRuby как скриптовый язык. В данный момент есть что-то такое:

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
container.put("view","Error.jsp");
container.runScriptlet("view = 'new.jsp';");
String view = (String)container.get("view");
```

и после этого по прежнему содержит "Error.jsp". Если не делать `put`, то `view == null`. Если есть какая-нибудь документация по этим моментам (официальная на гитхабе, по-моему, не описывает этот момент), то очень пригодились бы ссылки на неё. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Достаточно было инициализировать контейнер так:

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
```